# Как сделать так чтобы бот перешел по ссылке приглашению Telebot

Tags: python, telebot, бот, url

Как сделать так чтобы бот перешел по ссылке приглашению Telebot, Мне надо что бы когда я отправлял боту ссылку приглашение в группу, он переходил по ней и вступал в группу

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['chats_operator'])
def swipe_idies(message):
    markup2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    markup2.add(types.KeyboardButton('Добавить чат оператора'))
    asd = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что вы хотите сделать?', reply_markup=markup2)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(asd, prover)


def prover(message):
    if message.text == 'Добавить чат оператора':
        aaa = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                               "Вам нужно создать группу куда добавите бота в виде Админа, а после этого отправить ссылку приглошение в эту группу мне))")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(aaa, new_chat_url)

def new_chat_url(message):
    url = message.text
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, id_chat_now)

def id_chat_now(message):
    url_id = message.text
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text = url_id)
```

Comment: Думается мне что никак. Только вручную добавить бота

Comment: Печально просто я нашел бота который именно так и делает https://t.me/username_to_id_bot отправь ему ссылку в группу и воаля

Comment: Он зайдет и выйдет но заходить может, внимание вопрос как?!